# Zend Framework DB delete method strips values

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

Im trying to delete record from database depending where conditions. The query is pretty simple, but still Im getting strange results. What Im trying to do in ZF:

```
$where = array(
               $db->quoteInto('name = ?', $name),
               $db->quoteInto('surname = ?', $surname)
         );

$db->delete('users', $where);
```

While trying to debug Im getting:

```
DELETE FROM `users` WHERE (name = 'John') AND (surname = 'Johnson')
```

What is correct and working SQL statement. But later my values are getting stripped, so Im getting query like this:

```
DELETE FROM `users` WHERE (name = ) AND (surname = )
```

Depending debug results this happens in `Zend_Db_Statement` class (Statement.php), `_stripQuoted` method.

So finally as a result instead of one record deleted Im getting whole table cleared.

I've red the documentation and also Google'd for examples which are pretty much close to my situation. So Im not getting what is wrong with that?

Zend Framework version: 1.12

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter for delete should be a string. So I think you want:

```
$where = $db->quoteInto('name = ?', $name).' AND '.$db->quoteInto('surname = ?', $surname);    
$db->delete('users', $where);
```

Comment: Actually the problem was a little bit deeper in my script. But anyway your example works perfectly well. Thanks.